# Can't Access Xml Value from XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XmlTextReader object and I'm trying to read the xml below using it:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">STRING GOES HERE</string>
```

The code below compiles and runs however when I check xmReader.Value it is empty. I am confused because it should have the value "STRING GOES HERE". Can anyone help me figure out why I can't access the value?

```
string xmlstrdoc = "<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">STRING GOES HERE</string>";
XmlTextReader xmReader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlstrdoc));

while(xmReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(xmReader.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(xmReader.Value);
}
```

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not getting what you expect is because XmlTextReader.Read reads each node type. The first time Read() is called it reads the XmlNodeType.Element [NodeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.nodetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The second time Read() is called it will read the XmlNodeType.Text NodeType.

See the coding example here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.read(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Although it seems like you are looking for something more like [XmlDocument](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/).

Comment: Or `XDocument`, that has better interface.